# How to display aggregated historical data

Tags: reporting, charts

My CEO wants to view aggregated data, of such:

Assuming today we have
1000 New
500 In confirmation process
40 confirmed
10 converted

He wants to see the data in an aggregated display: (something like - who's been in that stage)

Total:

- 1550 New
- 550 ICP
- 40 Confirmed
- 10 converted

How can I achieve that?

Comment: sounds like you want to create a report and use bucketing if he just wants the numbers. If he wants to see "who", but grouped, then you'd need a summary report.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using BI (Business intelligence system ) to pick these data in aggregated format.